# Splitting an AJAX call which returns 5000 rows into multiple AJAX calls with 100 rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a ajax call, and I am loading the data returned into a datatable

Here is my jquery ajax call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var oTable;
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.prettyPrint() && prettyPrint();


    $('#load').click(function()
    {
        var v = $('#drp_v').val();
        var cnt = $('#drp_cnt').val();
        var ctg = $('#drp_ctg').val();
        var api = $('#drp_api').val();
        var nt = $('#drp_nt').val();
        $.post("ajax.php",
            {   'version':v,'category':ctg,
                'country':cnt,'network_id':nt,
                'api':api,'func':'show_datatable'},
                        function(data)
                        {
                            var aColumns = [];
                            var columns = [];
                            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
                            {
                                if(i>0)
                                    break;
                                keycolumns = Object.keys(data[i]); 
                                for(j = 0; j < keycolumns.length; j++)
                                {
                                    if($.inArray(keycolumns[j],aColumns.sTitle)<=0)
                                    {
                                        aColumns.push({sTitle: keycolumns[j]}) //Checks if
                                        columns.push(keycolumns[j]) //Checks if
                                    }                                  
                                }

                            }

                            var oTable = $('#jsontable').dataTable({
                                "columns":aColumns,
                                "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                                    "oTableTools": {
                                        "aButtons": [
                                            {
                                                    "sExtends": "csv",
                                                    "sButtonText": "CSV",
                                             }
                                        ]
                                    }
                            });
                            oTable.fnClearTable();
                            var row = []
                            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
                            {
                                for(var c = 0; c < columns.length; c++) 
                                {
                                        row.push( data[i][columns[c]] ) ;
                                }
                                oTable.fnAddData(row);
                                row = [];
                            }
                        },'json');
    });
});
</script>
```

And here's my php function

```
function show_datatable($version,$ctg,$cnt,$nt,$api)
{
    $cnt_table = "aw_countries_".$version;
    $ctg_table = "aw_categories_".$version;
    $off_table = "aw_offers_".$version;


    $sizeof_ctg = count($ctg);
    $cond_ctg = " ( ";
    for($c = 0; $c < $sizeof_ctg ; $c++)
    {
        $cond_ctg = $cond_ctg." $ctg_table.category = '".$ctg[$c]."' ";
        if($c < intval($sizeof_ctg-1))
            $cond_ctg = $cond_ctg." OR ";
        else if($c == intval($sizeof_ctg-1))
            $cond_ctg = $cond_ctg." ) ";
    }

    $sizeof_cnt = count($cnt);
    $cond_cnt = " ( ";
    for($cn = 0; $cn < $sizeof_cnt ; $cn++)
    {
        $cond_cnt = $cond_cnt." $cnt_table.country = '".$cnt[$cn]."' ";
        if($cn < intval($sizeof_cnt-1))
            $cond_cnt = $cond_cnt." OR ";
        else if($cn == intval($sizeof_cnt-1))
            $cond_cnt = $cond_cnt." ) ";
    }

    $sizeof_nt = count($nt);
    $cond_nt = " ( ";
    for($n = 0; $n < $sizeof_nt ; $n++)
    {
        $cond_nt = $cond_nt." $off_table.network_id = '".$nt[$n]."' ";
        if($n < intval($sizeof_nt-1))
            $cond_nt = $cond_nt." OR ";
        else if($n == intval($sizeof_nt-1))
            $cond_nt = $cond_nt." ) ";
    }

    $sizeof_api = count($api);
    $cond_api = " ( ";
    for($a = 0; $a < $sizeof_api ; $a++)
    {
        $cond_api = $cond_api." $off_table.api_key = '".$api[$a]."' ";
        if($a < intval($sizeof_api-1))
            $cond_api = $cond_api." OR ";
        else if($a == intval($sizeof_api-1))
            $cond_api = $cond_api." ) ";
    }

    $output         = "";

    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM $off_table,$cnt_table,$ctg_table
            WHERE  $off_table.id = $cnt_table.id
            AND $off_table.id = $ctg_table.id
            AND ".$cond_api."
            AND ".$cond_nt."
            AND ".$cond_cnt."
            AND ".$cond_ctg;

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $arr_result = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $arr_result[] = $row;
    }
    $arr_result_enc = json_encode($arr_result);
    echo $arr_result_enc;
}
```

Now, I want to modify this code. Say I want to work it like this:

I will call for v, and the AJAX will send me 100 rows once, then again 100 rows  and then again 100 rows.

I mean splitting the AJAX call to returns chunks of all the data one after another. Say something like there will be multiple times when the AJAX will be called, and each time it will send me 100 chunks of data.

While the work will be going on, there will be a progress bar with a cancel button.

If I click the cancel button, then if 3 times the AJAX function have been called, it will show me 300 data and then the AJAX will be stopped. The database will show only 300 data.

Answer (score 0):

**JQ:**

```
// counter that allows you to get a new set of rows
var step = 0;
// set variable if you want to restrict the number of rows will be loaded
var maxStep = 0;//
// how many rows should be returned
var count = 100;
// if the cancel button is pressed
var cancel = false;

$(function() {

    $('#load').click(function(){

        getData();

    })

    $('#cancel').click(function(){

        cancel = true;

    })

});

function getData()
{
    step++;

    //If cancel variable is set to true stop new calls
    if(cancel == true) return;
    // checks if the variable is set and limits how many rows to be fetched
    if(maxStep >0 and step >= maxStep) return;


    $.post('ajax.php'
        ,{
            'step':step,
            'count':count,
        }
        ,function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){   

             // do something with the data

             // when it finishes processing the data, call back function
             getData();

        }
        ,'json'
    )       
}
```

**AJAX.PHP**

```
$step = 0;
if(isset($_POST['step'])) $step = (int)$_POST['step'];

$count = 0;
if(isset($_POST['count'])) $count = (int)$_POST['count'];



if($step>0 and $count>0)
{
    $offset = ($step-1) * $count;        
    $limit = $offset.','.$count;

    // --------------        
    // your code here
    // --------------

    $sql = "SELECT *
        FROM $off_table,$cnt_table,$ctg_table
        WHERE  $off_table.id = $cnt_table.id
        AND $off_table.id = $ctg_table.id
        AND ".$cond_api."
        AND ".$cond_nt."
        AND ".$cond_cnt."
        AND ".$cond_ctg."
        LIMIT ".$limit;// <- limit

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $arr_result = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $arr_result[] = $row;
    }
    $arr_result_enc = json_encode($arr_result);
    echo $arr_result_enc;



    // echo rows
    echo json_encode($rows);        
}
```

Comment: i can see only three two echo... but you are recieving three on post callback.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really do not understand what you said. Although there is an error, it should be this: if (maxStep> 0 && step> = maxStep)

Comment: in this line, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) there are three variables, but in the ajax php page, you have only two echoes

Comment: echo json_encode($rows);  .This is from my other code, remained after copying. need to delete that part

Comment: total two echoes echo $arr_result_enc;



    // echo rows
    echo json_encode($rows);

Comment: you're right. `echo json_encode($rows);` .This is from my other code, remained after copying. need to delete that part

Answer (score 0):

Here's a heavy refactoring of the client-side code, in which the overall process is split into into three separate functions `getBatch()`, `makeRows()` and `showData()`, and kicked off by a very modified version of the original click handler.

Batching is controlled by `getBatch()`, which makes a ajax requests with two extra params - `start` and `batchSize`. These instruct the server-side script which batch of data to return.

`makeRows()` and `showData()` are just synchronous worker functions called by `getBatch()`.

I have assumed that progress is reported in a DOM element "#progress"`. You can report what you like here. I've kept it simple, showing the accumulated row count. By adding a batch counter, you could also show the number of completed batches.

Cancellation is achieved by setting outer var `allowBatch` to `false`. The currently requested batch will continue to be found but permission to retrieve further batches is withdrawn.

For good measure various DOM elements are enabled/disabled or shown/hidden at the start and end of the process. This can be omitted if not required.

```
var oTable;
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.prettyPrint() && prettyPrint();

    var aColumns = [], 
        columns = [],
        rows = [],
        $progress = $("#progress"),
        allowBatch;

    function getBatch(options) {
        return $.post("ajax.php", options, 'json').then(function(data) {
            var promise;
            if(allowBatch && data && data.length) {
                $progress.text(makeRows(data));
                options.start += batchsize;
                promise = getBatch(options);
            } else {
                promise = $.when(showData());
            }
            return promise;
        });
    }

    function makeRows(data) {
        var keycolumns, i, j;
        if(aColumns.length == 0) {
            keycolumns = Object.keys(data[0]);
            for(j = 0; j < keycolumns.length; j++) {
                if($.inArray(keycolumns[j], aColumns.sTitle) <= 0) {
                    aColumns.push({sTitle: keycolumns[j]});
                    columns.push(keycolumns[j]);
                }
            }
        }
        for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            rows.push( columns.map(function(col) {
                return data[i][col];
            }) );
        }
        return rows.length;
    }

    function showData() {
        var oTable = $('#jsontable').dataTable({
            'columns': aColumns,
            'sDom': 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            'oTableTools': {
                "aButtons": [{
                    "sExtends": "csv",
                    "sButtonText": "CSV"
                }]
            }
        });
        oTable.fnClearTable();
        $.each(rows, function(row) {
            oTable.fnAddData(row);
        });
        return oTable;
    }

    $('#load').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $load = $(this).attr('disabled', true),
            $cancel = $("#cancel").show();
        $progress.text('').show();
        aColumns.length = columns.length = rows.length = 0;
        allowBatch = true;
        getBatch({
            'version': $('#drp_v').val(),
            'category': $('#drp_ctg').val(),
            'country': $('#drp_cnt').val(),
            'network_id': $('#drp_nt').val(),
            'api': $('#drp_api').val(),
            'func': 'show_datatable',
            'start': 0,
            'batchsize': 100
        }).then(function(oTable) {
            // ... all done
            $load.attr('disabled', false);
            $cancel.hide();
            $progress.hide();
        });
    });

    $("#cancel").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        allowBatch = false;
    }).hide();

    $("#progress").hide();
});
```

*Tested only for parse errors, so may need to be debugged*

You will still need to modify the server-side script to accept the two additional parameter `start` and `batchsize` and compose its SQL accordingly. That should be fairly trivial.

The part I'm most uncertain about is `makeRows()`, which I struggled with slightly. If nothing works, look there first.