# PHP echo 5000 records and Unset

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I would like to echo records from a large data set of 300000.

echo first 5000 records than unset($data) and iterate until end of records in the mysql table.

Something like this,

1)

```
 for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        $data = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1000000);
        echo "peak_memory_usage = ” . memory_get_peak_usage(true) . “\n”;
        doSomething($data);

        //unset($data);

    }

    echo “for loop completed, memory now at ” . memory_get_usage(true) . “\n”;

    function doSomething($data) {
        echo “size:” . strlen($data) . “\n”;
    }
```

or something like this?

2)

```
 nRows = $pdo->query('select count(*) from employees')->fetchColumn();

        $users = new ArrayIterator(range(1, nRows)); // nRows are 3000000 test records
        foreach(new LimitIterator($users, 0, 50000) as $u) {
          echo $u, "\n";
        }
```

OR

3)   @Sameer would you like to add your suggestion  to the query below, I might be doing something wrong adding usleep-my coding flaws, which causes the issue of timeout when usleep is added.

```
 $data = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM user_details")->fetchAll();

        foreach ($data as $row) {
          echo $row['username']." -- ID :" .$row['user_id']. " -- FirstName :" .$row['first_name']. "<br />\n";
        }
```

The third 3) options works fine 50,000 records not much of load on RAM but CPU, is there a way to optimize this to reduce the load on CPU, imagine if 30 people run the same query it will maxed out the CPU? and if i add usleep(10) - it echos the records but with an error at the end saying timeout.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated please.

many thanks for reading my post.

- **Modified the original post as the objective is the same to reduce load on
  the server..  If you like my lengthy post, please vote guys, I am way
  behind and I would like to be a contributor in future.**

I stumble across an amazing solution by (Dm4Web) data load - amazing solution - but need HTML tables/append o be added and append the results.

## [Splitting an AJAX call which returns 5000 rows into multiple AJAX calls with 100 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223183/splitting-an-ajax-call-which-returns-5000-rows-into-multiple-ajax-calls-with-100)

## Getting error on line 49 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifie, when tried to run the script below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SQL Batch List AJAX and jQuery</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainform">
<h2>Fetch REcords 5000 at a time</h2>
<div id="listData">
<div>
<input id="load" name="load" type="button" value ="Load Data">
<input id="cancel" name="cancel" type="button" value ="Cancel">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script>

// counter that allows you to get a new set of rows
    var step = 0;
    // set variable if you want to restrict the number of rows will be loaded
    var maxStep = 0;//
    // how many rows should be returned
    var count = 5000;
    // if the cancel button is pressed
    var cancel = false;

    $(function() {

        $('#load').click(function(){

            getData();
        })

        $('#cancel').click(function(){
            cancel = true;
        })
    });

    function getData()
    {
        step++;

        //If cancel variable is set to true stop new calls
        if(cancel == true) return;
        // checks if the variable is set and limits how many rows to be fetched
        if(maxStep >0 $$ step >= maxStep)


        $.post('ajax.php'
        ,{
            'step':step,
            'count':count,
        }
        ,function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){   

        if(textStatus == "success")
        alert("Data: " + data);
                /*  foreach (data as $row) {

          echo $row['username']." -- ID :" .$row['user_id']. " -- FirstName :" .$row['first_name']. "<br />\n"; 
        } */
        if(textStatus == "error")
      alert("Error: " + jqXHR.status + ": " + jqXHR.statusText);


             // when it finishes processing the data, call back function
             getData();

        }
        ,'json'
    )       
}
</script>
</html>


    ==== ajax.php  =====


    step = 0;
    if(isset($_POST['step'])) $step = (int)$_POST['step'];

    $count = 0;
    if(isset($_POST['count'])) $count = (int)$_POST['count'];



    if($step>0 and $count>0)
    {
        $offset = ($step-1) * $count;        
        $limit = $offset.','.$count;

        // --------------        
        // your code here
        // --------------

        $data = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM user_details LIMIT .$limit")->fetchAll();
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $arr_result = array();
        foreach ($data as $row) {
               $arr_result[] = $row;
            }

        $arr_result_enc = json_encode($arr_result);
        echo $arr_result_enc;

        // echo rows
        //echo json_encode($rows);        
    }
```

Method 4)

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM employees";

  //$select_run = mysqli_query($conn, $select);
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$itemcount = $row['num']; // Roughly 300,000 total items


$batches = $itemcount / 2000; // Number of while-loop calls - around 120.
for ($i = 0; $i <= $batches; $i++) {
  $offset = $i * 2000; // MySQL Limit offset number
  $query = "SELECT first_name,last_name FROM employees  LIMIT 2500, $offset ";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo $row['first_name'];
  }

  echo "<BR>";
  echo "Run Number: ".$i."<br />";
  echo "<BR>";
}
```

Comment: Is this the same as the question you asked - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53787808/select-records-over-300000-in-batch-mode

Comment: Watch out for those NON-ASCII double quotes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select records over 300000 in batch mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53787808/select-records-over-300000-in-batch-mode)

Comment: @andrew  - The third 3) options works fine 50,000 records not much of load on RAM but CPU, is there a way to optimize this to reduce the load on CPU, imagine if 30 people run the same query it will maxed out the CPU? and if i add usleep(10) - it echos the records but with an error at the end saying timeout.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated please.

Comment: @ZaibTabs, add `usleep(100);` in for loop. Check my answer.

Comment: @Sameer would you like to add your suggestion to the query below, I might be doing something wrong adding usleep-my coding flaws, which causes the issue of timeout when usleep is added.

Comment: I have deleted the other post which is talking about client side load, this post includes both the section, client side and server side,   there is another method that i would go in my next step is caching data.

Comment: @ZaibTabs, there is default execution timeout for PHP. To increase it to 5 mins use `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);`. To set infinite execution time, use `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` as first line of your code.

Comment: @Samir, thanks, done that, at the moment my script is not working getting erros on line 49

Answer (score 1):

`$data` is already getting overwritten, so that's not the problem here.

Heavy loops create constant tension on the server, which increases the load.

You can add `sleep` of few microseconds to allow server free up resources and some breathing time, which will lower the server load. Use [usleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php) and set optimal microseconds.

```
for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    usleep(100);
    $data = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1000000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideas to fix your third attempt:

1. Select the columns you need instead of selecting *.
2. Cache the result so only need to run it once for each person that loads the page.
3. Add a LIMIT (paginate) so you only select the first 100 or 1000 rows instead of 50,000. This will also stop the browser from exploding when you load 50k rows at the same time.

Comment: I liked your suggestion 3    Limit is fine but i have to display all records in a long window without using paginate.  Any suggestions?

Comment: instead of echoing one line at a time, just print_r all of it, or json_encode the entire results and use javascript to load in browser.

Comment: Hi Andrew, please look at my modified code section 3),  using jquery .post or ajax method , which looks quite promising and I am still working on it.  But in the meantime if you have any suggestions, please feel free to update the script or sample working code would be helpful.